# Css components creation advice

Tags: magento-1.9, css

I want to create reusable css components/elements. For instance, when I create a new page with some elements like button, tooltip, list, breadcrumbs or any other element I want to be able to call one component css class and style that element. I know this is hard to achieve in M1 because of its structure and that is the reason I am asking it here. Google search for query "magento 1 css components" returns no results and that is one more reason to post this here. It seems unbelievable to me that no one ever try to "componentise" css elements in M1. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What you mean by reusable css ? you want to create a custom css which you add your classes and then you'll be able to call these classes in any page right ?

Comment: @Prince Right, that is my idea.

Comment: Look my answer please

Answer (score 0):

You have to create your new custom **css** then you load it for all Magento pages then you'll be able to call you classes as you need. the css should be in your theme xml as Magento system fallback between the `<default>/default>` tags, if you already have this file `local.xml` dont recreate it, add just the `action method`.

**1) app/design/frontend/{your package}/{your theme}/layout/local.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/mycustom.css</name></action>
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

**2) skin/frontend/{your package}/{your theme}/css/mycustom.css**

```
// some class {
...
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment but this is not something I am looking for. I work with Magento for many years and I try to achieve something much more abstract and advanced than including css file. Maybe I didn't formulated my question properly. I want to create system of custom css components for Magento.